# C# клиент для Java+netty сервера

Tags: java, c#, сеть, клиент-сервер, netty

Есть сервер на java + netty.io
Запуск сервера

```
            ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();

        serverBootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        //Здесь указываем размер буфера (8192 байта) и символ-признак конца пакета.
                        //Свои пакеты мы обычно терминируем символом с кодом 0, что соответствует nulDelimiter() в терминологии нетти
                        ch.pipeline().addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.nulDelimiter()));
                        ch.pipeline().addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder()); //Стандартный строковый декодер.
                        ch.pipeline().addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
                        ch.pipeline().addLast("hendler", new ServerHandler());
                    }
                })
                .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY,true)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE,true);

        ChannelFuture channelFuture = serverBootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(this.PORT)).sync();
        LoggingSystem.getLogger().log(Level.INFO,"NettyServer: Listen to users on "+ InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString()+":"+ this.PORT+"\n");

        // Wait until the server socket is closed.
        // In this example, this does not happen, but you can do that to gracefully
        // shut down your server.
        channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
```

Обработка сообщений

```
 @Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    //Вызывается когда от клиента приходит очередной пакет.
    try {
        new CommandProcessorSmall("cmdProcessor", new MsgChannel(ctx.channel(),msg.toString()),_debug).start();
    }catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Поток обработчик

```
  @Override
public void run() {
    try {
        if (_debug) {
            LoggingSystem.getLogger().log(Level.DEBUG,"IN  > "+msgChannel.message+"\n");
        }

        //Варианты ответов
        //String response = (String)_combat.processCommand(_nCtx);   //Игровая логика генерирует ответ
        //String response = "{\"resp\":\"Anwer in JSON format\"}";   //JSON
        String response = "<resp>Answer in XML format</resp>";       //XML
        ((Channel)(msgChannel.channel)).write(response+"\0");

        if (_debug) {
            LoggingSystem.getLogger().log(Level.DEBUG,"OUT > "+response+"\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Вся логика в том что каждый покет имеет в конце 0. И после получения пакета, мы его обрабатываем в созданном для него потоке, и вызываем обратную отправку на клиент ответа.

Сервер работает замечательно. А вот клиент, я не как не могу из кода C# подключится, отправить и прочитать сообщение. 
Вот так я могу отправить, сервер видит и выводит в лог, но я не получаю ответ обратно.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Буфер для входящих данных
        byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];

        // Соединяемся с удаленным устройством

        // Устанавливаем удаленную точку для сокета
        IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
        IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 7777);

        Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Соединяем сокет с удаленной точкой
        sender.Connect(ipEndPoint);

        string message = "Hi server"+"\0"

        Console.WriteLine("Сокет соединяется с {0} ", sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
        byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

        // Отправляем данные через сокет
        int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

        // Получаем ответ от сервера
        int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);

        Console.WriteLine("\nОтвет от сервера: {0}\n\n", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));

        // Освобождаем сокет
        sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        sender.Close();
    }
```

Я подозреваю что вся проблема в разделение пакетов. потому что сервер формирует пакет в котором последний идет 0. А клиент делит пакет так: Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec)

Как быть? Как послать сообщение и получить ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам разобрался)) вся проблема была в сервере. Он просто не отправлял ответ. А дело было в том что я писал данные в поток, но не отправлял использовав неправильные методы Netty.
Нужно было заменить

```
ctx.write(obj msg)
```

на

```
ctx.writeAndFlush(obj msg)
```